# Testing Void Method Objects and Events Parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I dont know how to test my calc in C# program because my methods are working exactly with (object sender, EventArgs e) parameters and with global variables. How could test to this method look like?

This is only one part of the code

```
private void buttonEq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    number2 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

    if (operation == "plus")
    {
        finRes = number1 + number2;
    }
    else if (operation == "minus")
    {
        finRes = number1 - number2;
    }
    else if (operation == "multiple")
    {
        finRes = number1 * number2;
    }
    else if (operation == "divide")
    {
        finRes = number1 / number2;
    }
    else if (operation == "exp")
    {
        finRes = Math.Pow(number1, number2);
    }
    else if (operation == "fac")
    {
        int result = number1;

        for (int i = (number1)-1; i > 0 ; i--)
        {
            result = result * i;    
            finRes = result;
        }
    }
    else if (operation == "sqrt")
    {
        finRes = Math.Sqrt(number1);
    }

    textBox2.Text = finRes.ToString();
    operation = "";
}
```

Comment: checkout mvvm pattern. You can't write unit test to access textBox2.Text . But if you bind it to a property in viewmodel you can definitely write unit test for that

Comment: Most of that code does not actually require the interface.  What about breaking it into two parts?  The UI code could handle getting the data to and from the UI and then the other could handle the actual work.  This would let you do a variety of testing on the actual work section without having to set up all the textbox stuff.

Comment: Abstract you processing code into its own class and unit test that.  Then use that class and its methods inside your form class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to refactor your code if you want to make calculation logic testable. In simpler words that means take out all those if/else into separate method. Now you can test the `Calculate` method or just call it from event handler, whatever.

```
void Calculate(int num1, int num2)
{
   // put all your if / else logic here
}

void buttonEq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Calculate(number1, number2);
}
```